# How to insert n contiguous elements into a std::vector whose element type is non-copyable?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to insert `n` contiguous non-copyable elements into a `std::vector`. I looked into the signature of [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) and [`emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace) and I found:

```
iterator insert( const_iterator pos, size_type count, const T& value );
```

But since `T` cannot be copied, this overload does not help. I also saw:

```
template< class... Args > 
iterator emplace( const_iterator pos, Args&&... args );
```

`emplace` solved the non-copyable problem, but it is only capable to insert one element per time. Since I want to insert `n` elements, the overall time complexity is the quadratic `O(n*size())`, which is unacceptable.

Is there any standard and portable way to do this?

Comment: Do you have to do this in the middle of the vector?

Comment: I think this is impossible by definition. If the type is not copyable, you can't make n copies of it. You have to construct them one at a time. If it's just the time complexity you're worried about, call reserve() first.

Comment: @RossSmith `reserve` won't help because if you're adding elements one by one, the `vector` has to move the existing elements each time.

Comment: How exactly do you want them constructed?  How expensive are they to move?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to insert `n` default constructed elements at the end of the `vector`, you can use `resize`.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v;
v.resize(v.size() + 10);              // append 10 elements
```

If you want to insert them in some other position, use the `insert` overload that takes a pair of iterators; construct the elements in a temporary array and move them into the `vector`

```
std::unique_ptr<int> arr[10];
v.insert(v.begin(),
         std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(arr)),
         std::make_move_iterator(std::end(arr)));
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f072e19df5cdbdf)

Comment: Thank you. This might be the closest approach.

Answer (score 1):

Emplace them at the end after a reserve.  O(n+m) for m new elements and n existing elements.

`std::rotate` them to where you want.  O(m+n-k) where `k` is the position in the vector you want them.

---

Alternatively write a generating input iterator that produces the elements in question.  Then use the `template< class InputIt > iterator insert( const_iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last );` overload.  This has more boilerplate, but avoids some moves.